# Finding and identifying the distribution of the sample variance

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, variance, chi-squared

Given a random sample of size $n$, from a normal population with variance $\sigma^2$, I am trying to find and identify the distribution of the sample variance, $S^2$.

I know that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$ ~ Chi-Square($n-1$) when the population is normal, but I'm not sure how to express the distribution of $S^2$.

Specifically, I want to figure out how to fill in the parameter for $S$~Chi Square( ... )

If anyone has any suggestions, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: The characterization $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \text{ChiSquared}(n-1)$ is fine. There question is a bit vague about the form of the answer; for $S^2$ you can either mention it is a scalar $\sigma^2/(n-1)$ times that chi-squared random variable, or you can spell out the PDF after the change of variables.

Comment: @angryavian How would I go about finding the parameters for $S^2$ ~ ChiSquare(   )?

Comment: $S^2$ doesn't follow a chi-squared distribution strictly speaking (even if some people might say so informally, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance)); it's a scaled version of the chi-squared distribution. I don't think there is a succinct answer to the question.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you so much!

Comment: "Scaled chi-squared" is fine, but if you want you can observe that $\chi_n^2$ is in fact the same as gamma distribution with shape $n/2$ and scale $2$. Scaling it by a factor $c$, you just get a new gamma distribution (same shape, scale multiplied by $c$).